# iPad safari crashing on simple form

Tags: ipad, html, mobile-safari

I have created a simple Form in html. Its working fine in desktop browsers. But in iPad's safari (simulator) when I try to type something in any of the text field of the form the iPad's safari is crashed...

Sometimes it allow me to enter 3-4 characters but mostly on 1-2 characters it crashed. How to test whats going wrong?

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Its iOS version 4.3 (238.2)

Comment: Are you watching any events with javascript, such as onkeydown on onchange?

Comment: no, just trying to type text in text boxes...

Comment: Could you share your HTML markup on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)? If your page has no javascript on it at all, you should make sure your code is [valid](http://validator.w3.org/).

Comment: Does it do the same on a device?

Comment: No! Its only on Lion and using latest iPad simulator (4.3) anyone else having same issue?

Comment: this fiddle crashes my iOS simulator (4.3) too http://jsfiddle.net/G3Fwd/ but only if I change input method to number. i.e I can enter text but if the first character is a number it crashes